# Profile summary by operation type

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I'm profiling my model in Tensorflow 2.0.  I'm able to get a profile & view with Tensorboard by following the instructions for a function.  I use tf.summary.trace_on & tf.summary.trace_export: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/graphs

Now I'd like to create a summary by operation type, similar to the node type summary in the tflite profiler (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark).

TensorFlow 1.14 tf.profile.Profiler looks to be able to do it with the 'cmd' option:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/profiler/profile

How do I do this with TensorFlow 2.0?